# Why does Visual Studio not add stored procedures to data structure on update?

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net

I've noticed recently that if I add a stored procedure to an existing ADO.NET entity data model through the GUI's "Update model from database..." that it does not generate the code to be able to access the stored procedure.

The only way I've found around this is to delete the existing ADO.NET model and start over.

Am I missing a step here? Is this the right behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio doesn't add the stored procedure automatically, which is a bit odd because it  does add it automatically when creating the model.

To add it, pull up the ADO.net model diagram, and

```
Add New...->Function Import...
```